# Accessing to other Fragment variables or elements from Fragment

Tags: android

For example I have 2 fragments including 1 integer variable and 1 TextView for each. One of them has a button. I want this button to change all Integers and TextViews including the other fragment. How can I access to Variable and TextView of the other fragment ? Please explain with example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment to Fragment Communication basically happens via an activity which generally hosts the Fragments, define an interface in your Fragment A, and let your Activity implement that Interface. Now you can call the interface method in your Fragment, and your Activity will receive the event. Now in your activity, you can call your second Fragment to update the textview(For example) with the received value:

```
// You Activity implements your interface which is defined in FragmentA
public class YourActivity implements FragmentA.TextClicked{
    @Override
    public void sendText(String text){
        // Get instance of Fragment B using FragmentManager
        FraB frag = (FragB)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
        frag.updateText(text);
    }
}


// Fragment A defines an Interface, and calls the method when needed
public class FragA extends Fragment{

    TextClicked mCallback;

    public interface TextClicked{
        public void sendText(String text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (TextClicked) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement TextClicked");
        }
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        mCallback.sendText("YOUR TEXT");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null; // => avoid leaking
        super.onDetach();
    }
}

// Fragment B has a public method to do something with the text
public class FragB extends Fragment{

    public void updateText(String text){
        // Here you have it
    }
}
```